# How to get C# WebSocketClient to listen for messages in an ongoing capacity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, websocket

I'm writing a program (really a game in Unity) which should act as a client to a Websocket server which is up and running separately.

I'm using the `System.Net.Websockets` `ClientWebSocket`. I have opened the connection, I can send messages, but unlike in a Javascript client where I would set up a callback function which would run each time the websocket client received a message I'm having a hard time understanding the intended flow for the C# API.

Here's a message handler that I've written:

```cs
public async Task HandleMessages() {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
            var messageBuffer = WebSocket.CreateClientBuffer(8192, 8192);
            WebSocketReceiveResult result;
            do {
                result = await ws.ReceiveAsync(messageBuffer, CancellationToken.None);
                ms.Write(messageBuffer.Array, messageBuffer.Offset, result.Count);
            }
            while (!result.EndOfMessage);

            if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Text) {
                var msgString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
                Debug.Log(msgString);
                var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<String, String>>(msgString);
                if (message["roomCode"] == RoomCode.ToLower()) {
                    // Message was intended for us!
                    Debug.Log("[WS] Got a message of type " + message["messageType"]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So after opening my Websocket connection initially if I call this:

```cs
await Task.WhenAll(HandleMessages());
```

then it will handle the first incoming message, but not any subsequent ones. I've tried many different things but I can't figure out how to get this task to run every time a message comes in.

Does anybody have any insight into the matter?

Comment: I'm not experienced with websockets, but I'd assume that `result.EndOfMessage` signifies when a complete message has been received, not when there is no potential for more data.

Comment: Yes that signifies the end of that message. However another message (many more in fact) will be sent, and I need to handle them each as they come in

Comment: And does calling `await ws.ReceiveAsync(...` again not work?

Comment: It would but the point of the websockets is to be receptive to messages whenever they are sent. How do I get this entire handler to run as a callback function (or C#ey equivalent concept) whenever a message is broadcast from the websocket server

Comment: it *seems* like all you need here is a `while` loop? (presumably inside the `ms` scope, and just make sure you set the `Length` and `Position` back to zero at the end of the loop)

Comment: Putting it in a while loop, it gets back to the `await ws.ReceiveAsync` line and never goes past there again. I would expect that when a new message comes in that call would return a value and we'd continue, but that's not the behavior I see

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out that there was a good element of user-error in this situation, as always.

I didn't understand some basic concepts of websockets, so when I thought I was broadcasting messages from my server I was really only sending them to certain clients. With the improvements suggested by Marc Gravell and more hours of tinkering my C# client code now looks like this:

```cs
public async Task HandleMessages() {
        try {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
                while (ws.State == WebSocketState.Open) {
                    WebSocketReceiveResult result;
                    do {
                        var messageBuffer = WebSocket.CreateClientBuffer(1024, 16);
                        result = await ws.ReceiveAsync(messageBuffer, CancellationToken.None);
                        ms.Write(messageBuffer.Array, messageBuffer.Offset, result.Count);
                    }
                    while (!result.EndOfMessage);

                    if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Text) {
                        var msgString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
                        var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<String, String>>(msgString);
                        if (message["roomCode"].ToLower() == RoomCode.ToLower()) {
                            Debug.Log("[WS] Got a message of type " + message["messageType"]);
                            // Message was intended for us!
                            switch (message["messageType"]) {
                                // handle messages here, unimportant to stackoverflow
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    ms.Position = 0;
                }
            }
        } catch (InvalidOperationException) {
            Debug.Log("[WS] Tried to receive message while already reading one.");
        }
    }
```

Once I configured the server to actually broadcast the messages I thought I was broadcasting (iterate over all clients and send the message), it now will read multiple messages. Thanks again for the help and hopefully this will help others in the future who are new to websockets have something to check for